# Vue 3 - не работает реактивность массива в объекте

Tags: vue.js, typescript

Есть простенький класс MyList

```
export class MyList {
  public items: string[] = [];

  public add(): void {
    this.items.push(`value ${this.items.length}`);
  }
}

export const myList = new MyList();
```

Делаю экземпляр этого класса реактивным, и ожидаю, что изменения будут отображаться в шаблоне.

```
<template>
  <p>myList.items.length={{ reactiveMyList.items.length }}</p>
  <button @click="handleAdd">Add</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive } from 'vue';
import { myList, MyList } from '@/MyList';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const reactiveMyList = reactive<MyList>(myList);
    const handleAdd = () => myList.add();
    return { reactiveMyList, handleAdd };
  },
});
</script>
```

Но по нажатию кнопки, ничего не происходит. Вроде во втором такие конструкции всегда работали...

Поэкспериментировав, обнаружил, что, если добавить реактивность в сам класс, то все работает.

```
export class MyList {
  public items: string[] = reactive([]);
  ...
```

Но, если же по аналогии переписать компонент:

```
<template>
  <p>items.length={{ items.length }}</p>
  <button @click="handleOk">Ok</button>
</template>

...

  setup() {
    const items = reactive<string[]>(myList.items);
    const handleOk = () => myList.add();
    return { items, handleOk };
  },
```

То шаблон вновь не реагирует на изменения, почему?

Причем, если механизм реактивности задействован локально, то все хорошо:

```
  setup() {
    const itemsLocal = reactive<string[]>([]);
    const handleOk = () => itemsLocal.push(`value ${itemsLocal.length}`);
    ...

<template>
  <p>items.length={{ items.length }}</p>
  <p>itemsLocal.length={{ itemsLocal.length }}</p>
  ...
```

Значит сбой вносит именно объектность, но как с этим бороться?

(ещё через 2 часа...) Ооо... скоро на стену полезу... Добавил в нажатие кнопки увеличение и локального массива и объектного:

```
const handleOk = () => {
  myList.add();
  itemsLocal.push(`value ${itemsLocal.length}`);
};
```

И ОБА работают! Убираю увеличение локального и вновь тишина... Ну так же не должно быть!

Comment: Можете объяснить мне один момент насчет `Vue3`? Почему на `Vue2` с `typescript`, в частности `class-component`, удобнее писать код, нежели в одном `setup()` и экспортировать тоже? Я просто не понимаю какие преимущества в `Vue3`, если вместе с `vue-class-component` куда удобнее описывать класс

Comment: С class-component не работал, до 3-го пользовался options API без ts, было очень мерзко бррр. В вебе недавно, поэтому переписывая проект на ts все сделал на классах, а в setup-е связываю объекты и компоненты. Это конечно совсем не в духе composition api, но сказывается десктопное прошлое, мыслить в парадигме объектов гораздо удобнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вызова метода добавления, надо было использовать не myList:

```
  setup() {
    const reactiveMyList = reactive<MyList>(myList);
    const handleAdd = () => myList.add();
    ...
```

а reactiveMyList:

```
const handleAdd = () => reactiveMyList.add();
```

Не думал, что можно обращаться как к проксированным свойствам, так и к исходным. Вот такой нюанс.